# The new element only append to the last element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, append, element

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="p1">This is a paragraph.</div>
<hr>
<div id="p2">This is another paragraph.</div>
```

And I want to append an element into all div element.

I write this code:

```
var forAppend = document.createElement("p");
forAppend.innerText = "This is NEW.";

var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
p1.appendChild(forAppend);

var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
p2.appendChild(forAppend);
```

As you can see result, just appended into last element:

```
This is a paragraph.
--------------------------
This is another paragraph.
This is NEW.
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/aumzeopj/3/)

When I use new variable for define element, works fine, see:

```
var forAppend = document.createElement("p");
forAppend.innerText = "This is NEW.";

var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
p1.appendChild(forAppend);

var forAppend = document.createElement("p");
forAppend.innerText = "This is NEW.";

var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
p2.appendChild(forAppend);
```

result:

```
This is a paragraph.
This is NEW.
--------------------------
This is another paragraph.
This is NEW.
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/aumzeopj/5/)

1. But why this happen (Only added to last item)?
2. And How can write better and cleanly code (For example with one `forAppend` var; maybe can get a instance from it)?

```js
var forAppend = document.createElement("p");
forAppend.innerText = "This is NEW.";

var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
p1.appendChild(forAppend);

var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
p2.appendChild(forAppend);
```

```html
<div id="p1">This is a paragraph.</div>
<hr>
<div id="p2">This is another paragraph.</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an element with two parents. (Otherwise, the DOM wouldn't have a tree structure anymore)

The thing you do is you create an element, append it to `p1` and than you still have the **same** element which is now a child of `p1` and say that it has to be at the end of `p2`, so after shortly being a child of `p1`, it switches to being a child of `p2`. So only the last command is visible to us, because this happens so fast.

The solution: just add two new elements.

Comment: I thought this was just a normal variable that could be added and sets anywhere.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. This is one of those strange things I find difficult to get used to; all these methods (`appendChild()`, `append()`, `prepend()`, etc.) act like "cut and paste", NOT "copy and paste" - which means you can't use the same element more than once without creating it again! Even `cloneNode()` is weird this way: while the clone leaves the original (cloned node) alone, **using** the clone is also a "cut and paste" operation - the clone disappears and if you want to append it again somewhere, you need to re-clone it...